# Find norm in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*I did not get any response, so I am posting my question again.*

**Question:**

Find a defining equation for the golden ratio: $\frac{1{+}\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Also find its norm in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$.

**My Work:**

The solutions to such an equation are :

$x=\frac{-b {\color{red}\pm} \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, the only way to get this  $\sqrt{5}$ is  $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$.
So we can see that $\frac{1{\color{red}-}\sqrt{5}}{2}$ will also be a root.

Now do I just develop $\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ and identify $a$,$b$ and $c $?

Also how do I do the second part of this question?

Comment: Yes, you get $x^2-(\phi+\phi')x+\phi\phi'$. This will be the minimal polynomial. The definition of norm you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm#Formal_definition), which tells you how to read the norm from the minimal polynomial. In your case it is just the constant term.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy So I was correct for the first part, and for the second part it is just the last term?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Why would it be the last term?

Comment: It is the product of the roots of the minimal polynomial raised to the power of the degree of the field extension [L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})], where $L$ is the field that you are considering. In your case $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. So, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})]=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the sum and the product

$$S=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=1$$

$$P=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=-1$$

And the quadratic we are looking for is

$$X^2-SX+P=X^2-X-1=0$$

Now for the norm we have

$$N(a+b\sqrt{5})=\sqrt{(a+b\sqrt{5})(a-b\sqrt{5})}$$

Comment: Ok I get that. Now how do I find the norm in $Q[\sqrt{5}]$?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: In this case a = 1/2 and b=-1/2 right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: So it would be 1?